# Find first src in php string

Tags: php

Before giving negative response please read.

It's given

```
[et_pb_image admin_label="Image" src="https://scontent-mia1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xaf1/v/t1.0-9/10848034_8974277986_916022442694_n.jpg?oh=9edafcdfb85e2c1b30ed77e6fb8&oe=566091B0" show_in_lightbox="off" url="" url_new_window="off" animation="left" sticky="off" align="left" force_fullwidth="off" always_center_on_mobile="on" use_border_color="off" border_color="#ffffff" border_style="solid" /]
```

How can i take the first src url?

this is not working for me

```
$new = preg_match('/src="(.*)|[^"]"/iS', $y->post_content, $img); 
echo '<pre>'; print_r($new); echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: What output do you get and what is the expected output?

Comment: output is 

Array
(
    [0] => ="
)

all i need is the image src link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The following should work:**

```
$myString = '[et_pb_image admin_label="Image" src="https://scontent-mia1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xaf1/v/t1.0-9/10848034_8974277986_916022442694_n.jpg?oh=9edafcdfb85e2c1b30ed77e6fb8&oe=566091B0" show_in_lightbox="off" url="" url_new_window="off" animation="left" sticky="off" align="left" force_fullwidth="off" always_center_on_mobile="on" use_border_color="off" border_color="#ffffff" border_style="solid" /]';

if(preg_match('/src="([^"]*)/i', $myString , $img)) {
    echo '<pre>'; 
    print_r($img);
    $src = $img[1];
    echo '</pre>';
    echo '<hr />' . $src; 
}
```

**What's wrong with your code:**

1. [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) returns a boolean. True when something is found.
2. `src="(.*)|[^"]"` is wrong. `src="` is correct. After that you're going to match everything until the end of the line. That's not what you want.
3. Furthermore `$img` should contain your result.

**Why the above is working:**

```
/src="   # match the src
(
    [^"] # matches everything except "
*)       # capture the content between the quotes "[the src]"
/ix
```

You can find a working version here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c71983343308a29272d90a441486474148ab3995

Comment: Nice! Make sure you understand why it wasn't working :)

Comment: I understood you explanation makes perfect sense